# Nature vs. Nurture: Is there any truth behind an ethnicity being predisposed to alcoholism? Is it really in my ancestral genes?

Tags: genetic-predisposition, alcoholism, ethnicity

My maternal grandfather was 50% Cherokee, and struggled his entire life with alcoholism, and died from the liver damage he had done from the excessive alcohol consumption. His son, my maternal uncle, is also an alcoholic and has had his life completely destroyed from this terrible addiction (ruined two marriages, none of his children will talk to him, lost his job, his home, and many friends, etc). My siblings and I don't have never touched alcohol due to religious reasons, but **can one be predisposed to be an alcoholic?** Looking at my family line, though from my vantage point (because of limited knowledge of my ancestral line), it seems to be from my maternal side... so I was wondering if it's in my **mitochondrial-dna?**

I know that the Native Americans often have a bad reputation in regards to their interaction with alcohol, but I know that there are many, many different reasons (beyond medical) that contributed to that, which... is truly unfortunate. But I don't want to go down that road (History Exchange). However, **I have also heard that there is something in certain Native American genes that predisposes us to becoming alcoholics.... but how true is this statement?** Is it just a racist statement based on history? **How much of it is based on nature and how much is based on nurture?**

Comment: Just wondering if my future children will be predisposed to it as well? I apologize if this is a flat out ignorant question... I read/hear different things.  So I do welcome correction and insight.

Comment: Also, if it helps... my grandfather is 50% Cherokee from my great grandmother who is 100% Cherokee. And my uncle is on my maternal side... that's why I was intially thinking mitochondrial DNA..... but.... I just realized that if must not be mitochondrial DNA because my maternal grandma didn't have it (and it's not in her family history).... my understanding of mitochondrial DNA may be confused. (I'm not even sure how alcoholism is passed through our genes... or if it even is). Again, I apologize for completely misunderstanding everything.  Please politely correct me. haha.

Comment: I don't know enough about this subject to write a good answer, but have a look at this http://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/arh301/3-4.htm